# How can I create a book made entirely of human skin?

Tags: internal-consistency

I am Darth obamaresh, darkest lord in the history of darklords. After a lifetime of wickedness and evil deeds, I have decided to preserve my evil discovered spells in a tome. This book is 666 pages long and meant to document my discoveries having to do with dark magic, as well as the vile acts I have committed.

This book, including the front and back cover as well as its pages will be made entirely of human skin, because that is the only acceptable method for a darklords of my caliber to use. It is also meant to be used very often on the regular, and must preserved down the centuries. My first thought was to use magic, but this is insufficient by itself to make this happen.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Quick, find some place with a major epidemic and volunteer to deal with the bodies.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, you need to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenger I can't give away the plot, but trust me on this one.

Comment: The sickening thing is these books (the skin part) exist.  No magic required.  Just murder.

Comment: @Cyn: Murder is not a requirement, just a handy supply of naturally-deceased corpses.  After all, when a body is laid out for viewing, as it is in some western funeral traditions, who takes off the clothing to see if the skin is still in place?  So any undertaker could do it...

Comment: @Cyn: And in the case of this particular dark lord, murder probably wasn't the MO. `After a lifetime of wickedness and evil deeds, I have decided to preserve my evil discovered spells in a tome. This book is 666 pages long and meant to document my discoveries having to do with dark magic, as well as the vile acts I have committed.` A whole lifetime's worth of research and "vile acts" only fills up 666 handwritten pages. That's what, 400 pages of printed A4?

Comment: @nzaman It's quality not quantity. :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Vellum and/or parchment**

This kind of thing has been done unfortunately. Human skin can be turned into leather or vellum and vellum is used to write on and bind books. Just use the same technology as for lambskin or calf-skin. Actually it's easier because you don't have to scrape off the fleece/coat.

---

> **10 Random Objects That Were Actually Made Out of Human Skin**
>
> https://www.ranker.com/list/actual-things-made-from-human-skin/jacob-shelton

---

> **vellum** Definition of vellum (Entry 1 of 2) 1 : a fine-grained unsplit lambskin, kidskin, or calfskin prepared especially for ***writing
>   on*** or for ***binding books***
>   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vellum

---

> **Parchment** is a writing material made from specially prepared untanned
>   skins of animals—primarily sheep, calves, and goats. ***It has been used
>   as a writing medium for over two millennia***. Vellum is a finer quality
>   parchment made from the skins of young animals such as lambs and young
>   calves.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchment

---

> **How parchment is made** - Domesday - BBC Two https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-SpLPFaRd0